# Java Biometric Finger Print with Secugen hamster iv

Tags: java

I'am trying to read finger print with secugen hamster iv device in my java app, i have already request the sdk, installed FDx SDK Pro for Windows v3.7, imported jars from FDx SDK Pro for Java v1.8. but now when i try to run a sample code i receive this error

```
**Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Windows\System32\jnisgfplib.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at SecuGen.FDxSDKPro.jni.JSGFPLib.<clinit>(JSGFPLib.java:78)
    at main.SecuGen.FDxSDKPro.samples.JSGD.jButtonInitActionPerformed(JSGD.java:783)
    at main.SecuGen.FDxSDKPro.samples.JSGD.access$1(JSGD.java:759)
    at main.SecuGen.FDxSDKPro.samples.JSGD$2.actionPerformed(JSGD.java:164)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)**
```

am runing windows 10 pro, jdk 1.8.0_131 please help

Answer (score 0):

In the first line it says that you are trying to read a 32Bit file on a 64Bit device which is not possible.

Comment: device, meaning windows 10 64 bit? I thot it supports both 64 and 32

Comment: Did you ever try to play an old 32Bit game on your Computer. It doesn't work aswell and the same thing happens to your .dll file. And yes i mean the windows :).

Comment: thankc i finally figured out where i was wrong. i had copied 64bit dll files to 32bit directory. its now working fine

Answer (score 0):

Use 32 bit apache tomcat because your using 32 bit dll or use 64 bit dll with 64 bit tomcat